# Negative altitudes in coordinates in Placemarks causing errors with google maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

A few weeks ago some of my KML in google maps stopped working without me doing anything.

I've put it through the validator and it says its a problem with the altitude not being correct, but I cant seem to figure it out.

It seems that negative altitudes dont work.

If i remove the coord with the negative altitude it works fine.

Anyone know what Im doing wrong or how to correct it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Placemark id="rob">
 <name>test</name>
 <description>
  Robs Map
 </description>
 <LineString>
 <tessellate>1</tessellate>
 <coordinates>
-3.006974,51.560436,10.929999
-3.006605,51.561489,10.929999
-3.004138,51.582977,-3.870000
-2.699919,51.387234,180.199997
 </coordinates>
 </LineString>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

The error I get from the validator is:

This feed does not validate.

line 15, column 0: Invalid value for coordinates: -3.870000 [help]

Thanks,

Rob D.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on localhost and also on this online service: [display-kml.appspot.com](http://display-kml.appspot.com/)
Which validator do you use?

Comment: Hi,

I use the official Google Maps validator:

http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com.ar/2007/06/validate-your-kml-online-or-offline.html

And I have the kml above in the following file:

http://www.darkblueplanet.com/travel/mapdata/test.kml

It fails everytime for me.